# Update to Spring Boot 3 - Logging not longer work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

After updating to Spring Boot 3 the logging does not longer work. No line is written into to logfiles. I have the file logback-spring.xml in resources folder. This file also exists in the jar-file (test-1.1.1.jar\BOOT-INF\classes).

- This only happens on the productive envorionment (starting application via jar file).
- Starting application within Eclipse is working fine and makes no problems.

In my opinion the logback file is used by spring boot by starting from jar-file, because empty logfiles with the defined file name in the logback-spring.xml is generated by starting the application.

It simply does not long any entry. Does anyone have an idea?

Content of logback-spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml> 

<configuration>

  <if condition='property("SERVER_LOG_PATH").isEmpty()'>
    <then>
      <property name="SERVER_LOG_PATH" value="./log" />
    </then>
  </if>

  <springProfile name="dev">
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
      <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
      </filter>
      <encoder>
        <pattern>%d %5p | %t | %-55logger{55} | %m %n</pattern>
      </encoder>
    </appender>
  </springProfile>

  <appender name="DEBUG_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>DEBUG</level>
    </filter>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${SERVER_LOG_PATH}/test_%d{yyyyMMdd}_debug_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
      <maxFileSize>300MB</maxFileSize>
      <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
      <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
      <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
      <pattern>%d %5p | %t | %-55logger{55} | %m %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="INFO_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${SERVER_LOG_PATH}/test_%d{yyyyMMdd}_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
      <maxFileSize>300MB</maxFileSize>
      <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
      <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
      <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
      <pattern>%d %5p | %t | %-55logger{55} | %m %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="INFO_FILE" />

    <springProfile name ="dev">
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </springProfile>
  </root>

  <logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari" level="DEBUG" />

</configuration>
```

Maybe this helps - the following is written to the console:

```
15:22:34,079 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - This is logback-classic version 1.4.11
15:22:34,087 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@727eb8cb - Here is a list of configurators discovered as a service, by rank: 
15:22:34,087 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@727eb8cb -   org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.RootLogLevelConfigurator
15:22:34,087 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@727eb8cb - They will be invoked in order until ExecutionStatus.DO_NOT_INVOKE_NEXT_IF_ANY is returned.
15:22:34,087 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@727eb8cb - Constructed configurator of type class org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.RootLogLevelConfigurator
15:22:34,093 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@727eb8cb - org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.RootLogLevelConfigurator.configure() call lasted 1 milliseconds. ExecutionStatus=INVOKE_NEXT_IF_ANY
15:22:34,093 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@727eb8cb - Trying to configure with ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.SerializedModelConfigurator
15:22:34,094 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@727eb8cb - Constructed configurator of type class ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.SerializedModelConfigurator
15:22:34,110 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.scmo]
15:22:34,113 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.scmo]
15:22:34,113 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@727eb8cb - ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.SerializedModelConfigurator.configure() call lasted 19 milliseconds. ExecutionStatus=INVOKE_NEXT_IF_ANY
15:22:34,113 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@727eb8cb - Trying to configure with ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator
15:22:34,114 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@727eb8cb - Constructed configurator of type class ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator
15:22:34,116 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
15:22:34,116 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:nested:/C:/Users/thomas/Desktop/test-1.1.1.jar/!BOOT-INF/classes/!/logback.xml]
15:22:34,137 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@39d9314d - URL [jar:nested:/C:/Users/thomas/Desktop/test-1.1.1.jar/!BOOT-INF/classes/!/logback.xml] is not of type file
15:22:34,403 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.conditional.IfModelHandler - Condition [property("SERVER_LOG_PATH").isEmpty()] evaluated to true on line 6
15:22:34,411 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ImplicitModelHandler - Ignoring unknown property [springProfile] in [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
15:22:34,413 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Processing appender named [DEBUG_FILE]
15:22:34,413 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
15:22:34,430 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@194481424 - setting totalSizeCap to 20 GB
15:22:34,433 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@194481424 - Archive files will be limited to [300 MB] each.
15:22:34,457 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@194481424 - No compression will be used
15:22:34,459 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@194481424 - Will use the pattern ./log/test_%d{yyyyMMdd}_debug_%i.log for the active file
15:22:34,482 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@5b7a8434 - The date pattern is 'yyyyMMdd' from file name pattern './log/test_%d{yyyyMMdd}_debug_%i.log'.
15:22:34,482 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@5b7a8434 - Roll-over at midnight.
15:22:34,488 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@5b7a8434 - Setting initial period to 2023-12-21T14:22:34.488Z
15:22:34,496 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@194481424 - Cleaning on start up
15:22:34,503 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ImplicitModelHandler - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
15:22:34,503 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.helper.TimeBasedArchiveRemover - first clean up after appender initialization
15:22:34,504 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.helper.TimeBasedArchiveRemover - Multiple periods, i.e. 32 periods, seem to have elapsed. This is expected at application start.
15:22:34,540 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.helper.TimeBasedArchiveRemover - Removed  0 Bytes of files
15:22:34,553 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[DEBUG_FILE] - Active log file name: ./log/test_20231221_debug_0.log
15:22:34,553 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[DEBUG_FILE] - File property is set to [null]
15:22:34,555 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Processing appender named [INFO_FILE]
15:22:34,555 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
15:22:34,556 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1548081008 - setting totalSizeCap to 20 GB
15:22:34,556 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1548081008 - Archive files will be limited to [300 MB] each.
15:22:34,556 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1548081008 - No compression will be used
15:22:34,556 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1548081008 - Will use the pattern ./log/test_%d{yyyyMMdd}_%i.log for the active file
15:22:34,556 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@2ce6c6ec - The date pattern is 'yyyyMMdd' from file name pattern './log/test_%d{yyyyMMdd}_%i.log'.
15:22:34,556 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@2ce6c6ec - Roll-over at midnight.
15:22:34,556 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@2ce6c6ec - Setting initial period to 2023-12-21T14:22:34.556Z
15:22:34,557 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1548081008 - Cleaning on start up
15:22:34,557 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ImplicitModelHandler - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
15:22:34,557 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.helper.TimeBasedArchiveRemover - first clean up after appender initialization
15:22:34,557 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.helper.TimeBasedArchiveRemover - Multiple periods, i.e. 32 periods, seem to have elapsed. This is expected at application start.
15:22:34,558 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[INFO_FILE] - Active log file name: ./log/test_20231221_0.log
15:22:34,558 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[INFO_FILE] - File property is set to [null]
15:22:34,558 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.RootLoggerModelHandler - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
15:22:34,559 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderRefModelHandler - Attaching appender named [DEBUG_FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
15:22:34,560 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderRefModelHandler - Attaching appender named [INFO_FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
15:22:34,563 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ImplicitModelHandler - Ignoring unknown property [springProfile] in [ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger]
15:22:34,564 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting level of logger [xx.xxx] to DEBUG
15:22:34,564 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting level of logger [com.zaxxer.hikari] to DEBUG
15:22:34,564 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting level of logger [com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler] to DEBUG
15:22:34,564 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting level of logger [com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler] to ERROR
15:22:34,564 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@1bae316d - End of configuration.
15:22:34,565 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@147a5d08 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
15:22:34,565 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@727eb8cb - ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configure() call lasted 451 milliseconds. ExecutionStatus=DO_NOT_INVOKE_NEXT_IF_ANY

15:22:35,023 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@4efcf8a - URL [jar:nested:/C:/Users/thomas/Desktop/test-1.1.1.jar/!BOOT-INF/classes/!/logback.xml] is not of type file
15:22:35,033 |-WARN in org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.SpringProfileIfNestedWithinSecondPhaseElementSanityChecker@7a138fc5 - <springProfile> elements cannot be nested within an <appender>, <logger> or <root> element
15:22:35,034 |-WARN in org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.SpringProfileIfNestedWithinSecondPhaseElementSanityChecker@7a138fc5 - Element <root> at line 59 contains a nested <springProfile> element at line 63
15:22:35,037 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.conditional.IfModelHandler - Condition [property("SERVER_LOG_PATH").isEmpty()] evaluated to true on line 6
15:22:35,040 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Processing appender named [DEBUG_FILE]
15:22:35,040 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
15:22:35,041 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@932885627 - setting totalSizeCap to 20 GB
15:22:35,041 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@932885627 - Archive files will be limited to [300 MB] each.
15:22:35,041 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@932885627 - No compression will be used
15:22:35,042 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@932885627 - Will use the pattern ./log/test_%d{yyyyMMdd}_debug_%i.log for the active file
15:22:35,042 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@307765b4 - The date pattern is 'yyyyMMdd' from file name pattern './log/test_%d{yyyyMMdd}_debug_%i.log'.
15:22:35,042 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@307765b4 - Roll-over at midnight.
15:22:35,042 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@307765b4 - Setting initial period to 2023-12-21T14:22:35.042Z
15:22:35,043 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@932885627 - Cleaning on start up
15:22:35,043 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ImplicitModelHandler - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
15:22:35,043 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.helper.TimeBasedArchiveRemover - first clean up after appender initialization
15:22:35,043 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.helper.TimeBasedArchiveRemover - Multiple periods, i.e. 32 periods, seem to have elapsed. This is expected at application start.
15:22:35,043 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[DEBUG_FILE] - Active log file name: ./log/test_20231221_debug_0.log
15:22:35,043 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[DEBUG_FILE] - File property is set to [null]
15:22:35,044 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Processing appender named [INFO_FILE]
15:22:35,044 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
15:22:35,044 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1251897263 - setting totalSizeCap to 20 GB
15:22:35,044 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1251897263 - Archive files will be limited to [300 MB] each.
15:22:35,045 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1251897263 - No compression will be used
15:22:35,045 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1251897263 - Will use the pattern ./log/test_%d{yyyyMMdd}_%i.log for the active file
15:22:35,045 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@2c95ac9e - The date pattern is 'yyyyMMdd' from file name pattern './log/test_%d{yyyyMMdd}_%i.log'.
15:22:35,045 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@2c95ac9e - Roll-over at midnight.
15:22:35,045 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@2c95ac9e - Setting initial period to 2023-12-21T14:22:35.045Z
15:22:35,045 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1251897263 - Cleaning on start up
15:22:35,046 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ImplicitModelHandler - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
15:22:35,046 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.helper.TimeBasedArchiveRemover - first clean up after appender initialization
15:22:35,046 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.helper.TimeBasedArchiveRemover - Multiple periods, i.e. 32 periods, seem to have elapsed. This is expected at application start.
15:22:35,046 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[INFO_FILE] - Active log file name: ./log/test_20231221_0.log
15:22:35,046 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[INFO_FILE] - File property is set to [null]
15:22:35,047 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting level of logger [xx.xxx] to DEBUG
15:22:35,047 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@4e4efc1b - Propagating DEBUG level on Logger[xx.xxx] onto the JUL framework
15:22:35,048 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting level of logger [com.zaxxer.hikari] to DEBUG
15:22:35,048 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@4e4efc1b - Propagating DEBUG level on Logger[com.zaxxer.hikari] onto the JUL framework
15:22:35,048 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting level of logger [com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler] to DEBUG
15:22:35,048 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@4e4efc1b - Propagating DEBUG level on Logger[com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler] onto the JUL framework
15:22:35,048 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting level of logger [com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler] to ERROR
15:22:35,048 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@4e4efc1b - Propagating ERROR level on Logger[com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler] onto the JUL framework
15:22:35,048 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@459f7aa3 - End of configuration.
15:22:35,048 |-INFO in org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.SpringBootJoranConfigurator@7cc586a8 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

Comment: It seems that the springProfile configuration causes the issue. After removing is everything is working finde. It seems that this was removed with Spring Boot 3, because it is not longer described in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.x/reference/html/howto-logging.html Is there another way to log to console only for a specific profile?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update/add following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
    <version>7.4</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Spring Boot 3 works with version 7.4.

Ref:https://github.com/zalando/logbook/blob/180a1cce9f8f77f6775907bafa8bf121afdd9571/logbook-parent/pom.xml#L107